# Expression Condition on a object

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have an object and a linq expression. I want to validate the object by the expression like this:

```
    obj: Account account = new Account(0);
    exp: (a => a.balance == 0)

    public bool IsAccountClosed(Account account, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> matchingCriteria)
    {
       // ... ??? 
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to validate an object by a expression

Comment: yes I can but this is an example. I want to do this by using expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an `Expression`, just a `Func`, and its first generic parameter should be `Account`:

```
public bool CheckAccountCriteria(Account acccount, Func<Account, bool> matchingCriteria)
{
    if (matchingCriteria(account)) 
    {
        // matches the criteria
    }
}
```

You could also use `Predicate<Account>`, which is probably the more idiomatic way to go about testing a value for a condition:

```
public bool CheckAccountCriteria(Account acccount, Predicate<Account> matchingCriteria)
{
    if (matchingCriteria(account)) 
    {
        // matches the criteria
    }
}
```

but as Surgeon of Death points out, you might just be making things unnecesarilly convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question? if you want to check the account you can do it like this without linq expression.

```
public bool IsAccountClosed(Account acccount)
{
   return account.balance == 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to do this by using expressions